# Writing RSPECs / Failed tests. What is wrong with my rspec files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to write specs for my Pinterest clone app. My app is working as intended but is failing my tests. What am I not understanding?

pin_controller_spec

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec-rails'
RSpec.describe PinsController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it 'renders the index template' do
      get :library
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end

    it 'populates @pins with all pins' do
      get :index
      expect(assigns[:pins]).to eq(Pin.all)
    end
  end


  describe "GET new" do
    it 'responds with successfully' do
      get :new
      expect(response.success?).to be(true)
    end

    it 'renders the new view' do
      get :new
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    end

    it 'assigns an instance variable to a new pin' do
      get :new
      expect(assigns(:pin)).to be_a_new(Pin)
    end
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    before(:each) do
      @pin_hash = {
        title: "Rails Wizard",
        url: "http://railswizard.org",
        slug: "rails-wizard",
        text: "A fun and helpful Rails Resource",
      resource_type: "rails"}
    end

    after(:each) do
      pin = Pin.find_by_slug("rails-wizard")
      if !pin.nil?
        pin.destroy
      end
    end

    it 'responds with a redirect' do
      post :create, pin: @pin_hash
      expect(response.redirect?).to be(true)
    end

    it 'creates a pin' do
      post :create, pin: @pin_hash
      expect(Pin.find_by_slug("rails-wizard").present?).to be(true)
    end

    it 'redirects to the show view' do
      post :create, pin: @pin_hash
      expect(response).to redirect_to(pin_url(assigns(:pin)))
    end

    it 'redisplays new form on error' do
      # The title is required in the Pin model, so we'll
      # delete the title from the @pin_hash in order
      # to test what happens with invalid parameters
      @pin_hash.delete(:title)
      post :create, pin: @pin_hash
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    end

    it 'assigns the @errors instance variable on error' do
      # The title is required in the Pin model, so we'll
      # delete the title from the @pin_hash in order
      # to test what happens with invalid parameters
      @pin_hash.delete(:title)
      post :create, pin: @pin_hash
      expect(assigns[:errors].present?).to be(true)
    end

  end

end
```

```
require "spec_helper"

RSpec.describe "Our Application Routes" do
  describe "GET /pins/name-:slug" do

    it 'renders the pins/show template' do
      pin = Pin.first
      get "/pins/name-#{pin.slug}"
      expect(response).to render_template("pins/show")
    end
    it 'populates the @pin variable with the appropriate pin' do
      pin = Pin.first
      get "/pins/name-#{pin.slug}"
      expect(assigns[:pin]).to eq(pin)
    end

  end
end
```

console log

```
Failures:

  1) PinsController GET index renders the index template
     Failure/Error: get :library

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"library", :controller=>"pins"}
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:57:in `generate'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:744:in `generate'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:775:in `generate'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:770:in `generate_extras'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:494:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:395:in `get'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
     # ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) PinsController POST create responds with a redirect
     Failure/Error: post :create, pin: @pin_hash

     ArgumentError:
       unknown keyword: pin
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:460:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:403:in `post'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
     # ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) PinsController POST create creates a pin
     Failure/Error: post :create, pin: @pin_hash

     ArgumentError:
       unknown keyword: pin
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:460:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:403:in `post'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
     # ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:57:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) PinsController POST create redirects to the show view
     Failure/Error: post :create, pin: @pin_hash

     ArgumentError:
       unknown keyword: pin
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:460:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:403:in `post'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
     # ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) PinsController POST create redisplays new form on error
     Failure/Error: post :create, pin: @pin_hash

     ArgumentError:
       unknown keyword: pin
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:460:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:403:in `post'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
     # ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:71:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) PinsController POST create assigns the @errors instance variable on error
     Failure/Error: post :create, pin: @pin_hash

     ArgumentError:
       unknown keyword: pin
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:460:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:403:in `post'
     # /Users/dl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
     # ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:80:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) Our Application Routes GET /pins/name-:slug renders the pins/show template
     Failure/Error: get "/pins/name-#{pin.slug}"

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `slug' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/requests_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'

  8) Our Application Routes GET /pins/name-:slug populates the @pin variable with the appropriate pin
     Failure/Error: get "/pins/name-#{pin.slug}"

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `slug' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/requests_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'

Finished in 1.63 seconds (files took 4.26 seconds to load)
12 examples, 8 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:5 # PinsController GET index renders the index template
rspec ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:51 # PinsController POST create responds with a redirect
rspec ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:56 # PinsController POST create creates a pin
rspec ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:61 # PinsController POST create redirects to the show view
rspec ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:66 # PinsController POST create redisplays new form on error
rspec ./spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:75 # PinsController POST create assigns the @errors instance variable on error
rspec ./spec/requests/requests_spec.rb:6 # Our Application Routes GET /pins/name-:slug renders the pins/show template
rspec ./spec/requests/requests_spec.rb:11 # Our Application Routes GET /pins/name-:slug populates the @pin variable with the appropriate pin
```

```
FProcessing by PinsController#index as HTML
  Rendering pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Template rendering was prevented by rspec-rails. Use `render_views` to verify rendered view contents if necessary.
  Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  Template rendering was prevented by rspec-rails. Use `render_views` to verify rendered view contents if necessary.
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 8.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
.Processing by PinsController#new as HTML
  Rendering pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Template rendering was prevented by rspec-rails. Use `render_views` to verify rendered view contents if necessary.
  Rendered pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (215.7ms)
  Template rendering was prevented by rspec-rails. Use `render_views` to verify rendered view contents if necessary.
Completed 200 OK in 219ms (Views: 216.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The success? predicate is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.0. Please use successful? as provided by Rack::Response::Helpers. (called from block (3 levels) in <top (required)> at /Users/dl/Desktop/SkillCrush/RubyOnRails/Rails/rails-pinning-app/spec/controllers/pins_controller_spec.rb:20)
.Processing by PinsController#new as HTML
  Rendering pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Template rendering was prevented by rspec-rails. Use `render_views` to verify rendered view contents if necessary.
  Rendered pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  Template rendering was prevented by rspec-rails. Use `render_views` to verify rendered view contents if necessary.
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
.Processing by PinsController#new as HTML
  Rendering pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Template rendering was prevented by rspec-rails. Use `render_views` to verify rendered view contents if necessary.
  Rendered pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
  Template rendering was prevented by rspec-rails. Use `render_views` to verify rendered view contents if necessary.
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Also says "Template rendering was prevented by rspec-rails. Use `render_views` to verify rendered view contents if necessary. Not sure what that means ? I tried placing `render_template` with `render_views` in `pin_controller_spec.rb without much luck.

pin_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
#READ
  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end
  def show
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  end
  def show_by_name
     @pin = Pin.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
     render :show
  end
#CREATE
  def new
     @pin = Pin.new  
  end

  def create
    @pin = Pin.create(pin_params)
    @pin.slug = create_slug(@pin)
    @pin.save
    if @pin.persisted?
      redirect_to @pin
    else
      @errors = @pin.errors
      render :new
    end
  end
#UPDATE
  def edit
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    render :edit
  end
  def update
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    if @pin.update_attributes(pin_params)
      redirect_to pin_path(@pin)
    else
      @errors = @pin.errors
      render :edit
    end
  end

#DESTROY
  def destroy
    #@pin.delete(pin_params)
    pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    pin.destroy
    #pin.destroy(pin_params)
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Your ppin has been deleted"
  end
#PRIVATE METHODS  
  private
  #pin_params
  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :url, :slug, :text, :category_id, :image)
  end
  #generate slug
  def create_slug(pin)
    pin_slug = pin.title.downcase.parameterize(separator: "-")
    pin_slug
  end

end
```

Comment: i would add `type:controller` to the spec initial line.

Comment: Maybe 1) `get :index`. 2-6) `post :create, params { pin: @pin_hash }`. 7-8) Your `routes.rb` is incorrectly specified.